# How to Change Swipe Animation in FlipView Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, flipview

I have flipview in my windows 8 metro app. I have made my own animation on scroll of mouse on flipview and handled the default animation for that but when i try this app on simulator when I swipe for changing selected index it shows first there default animation and then animation created by me. So I want to disable default animation in case of touch.  I have tried to change template but I did not find anything that will help me.

Please tell me if there is any way .